# How Can I Create an Ant File For a Set of .java Classes That are Part of the Same Package?

Tags: java, ant, jar, compilation

I have four classes which are all part of the same package. Account, SavingsAccount,CheckingAccount, and Bank. They are all part of the package banker. I tried compiling them on the command line one at at time into .class 's then I used [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) to attempt to compile into a .jar. However I got errors stating that various "symbols" related to other classes could not be found. If there was a reference to Account in SavingsAccount the compiler would scream at, for example.

So, one how can I compile this on command line in a separate environment from my IDE where it was developed?

And two, how can I create a makefile/ant build.xml file that will automate the .java to .jar process for me? I have reviewed the various websites and I can't find any tutorials on creating an ant file that contains multiple .java files.

Thank you!

Comment: One must come before two; in order to do something with a makefile, you must first know how to do it *without* a makefile.

Comment: I'm getting errors "Cannot find symbol" all over the place when referring to my classes. They worked perfectly fine in the IDE, but now that I am trying to compile in terminal everything is messing up. Is there any obvious reason here?

Comment: You make no mention of what IDE you're using, presumably Eclipse. If you look carefully you'll discover a ".classpath" file at the root of your project. It will contain a list of jars that are added automatically to the javac command by the IDE which explains the lack of errors.